# Generate all possible Turing functions of a type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, turing-machines

I want to bruteforce some Turing machines in Haskell. These Turing machines have a Delta function of type:

```
type Delta state alphabetSymbol
   = (state -> alphabetSymbol -> (alphabetSymbol, Direction, state))
```

where

```
data Direction
= L
| R
deriving (Eq, Show, Enum)
```

In the concrete example I want to bruteforce, my states and symbol types are the following enums:

```
data State
= Q0
| Q1
| QF
deriving (Show, Eq, Enum)

data Symbol
= Zero
| One
| Blank
deriving (Show, Eq, Enum)
```

I want to generate (almost) all possible Delta functions with these sum types efficiently. Almost, because the function will never be called with `QF` as a `state`, so I don't need to worry about `QF` in input.

I have already written a stupid higher level function that generates them based on instructions, but it looks stuff up in a list, which makes it pretty inefficient. Also, I want to do this *beautifully!*

Comment: For the given `Symbol`, `State` and `Direction`, there are 198'359'290'368 possible delta functions, so the problem is not that much with how you generate it, it is "intrensically" not very scalable.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Right, I need to point out that `QF` will never turn up in the arguments of the function when it is called, so we don't need to have that in the product, so there should just be two input states. That lowers the number of possible functions to 387 420 489, if I am correct.

Comment: So, what is your question. Included it above in the question section, along with what you've tried, and specific problems you are having with your attempt.

Comment: @user3760874 If `QF` never shows up, there are only (2 • 3 • 3)^((3-1) • 3) = 18⁶ = 34 012 224 combinations. Further it's possible to use symmetry of states and head-movement to further reduce the number of interesting cases.

Comment: You may be looking for something like [smallcheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/smallcheck).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the [turing-machines] tag to your question.

### Types for the Turing machine:

The system of types involved in the problem can be made more detailed:

```
import qualified  Data.List   as  L
import qualified  Data.Map    as  M
import qualified  Data.Maybe  as  Mb
import qualified  Data.Tuple  as  T


type Delta state symbol direction
    = ( state -> symbol -> (state, symbol, direction) )


data State     = Q0 | Q1 | QF        deriving (Show, Eq, Enum, Ord, Bounded)

data Symbol    = Zero | One | Blank  deriving (Show, Eq, Enum, Ord, Bounded)

data Direction = L | R               deriving (Eq, Show, Enum, Ord, Bounded)

stateList     = [minBound .. maxBound] :: [State]
symbolList    = [minBound .. maxBound] :: [Symbol]
directionList = [minBound .. maxBound] :: [Direction]

type DeltaTable =
    M.Map  (State, Symbol)   (State, Symbol, Direction)

type DeltaFunc = Delta  State Symbol Direction

tmInpList :: [ (State, Symbol) ]
tmInpList = do 
              st <- filter  (/= QF)  stateList  -- cannot start from state QF
              sy <- symbolList
              return (st, sy)

tmInpListSize = length tmInpList

tmMapInpList :: M.Map Int (State, Symbol)
tmMapInpList = M.fromList $ zip  [ 0 .. (tmInpListSize-1) ]  tmInpList

tmOutList :: [ (State, Symbol, Direction) ]
tmOutList = do 
              st  <- stateList
              sy  <- symbolList
              dir <- directionList
              return (st, sy, dir)

tmOutListSize = length tmOutList

tmMapOutList :: M.Map Int (State, Symbol, Direction)
tmMapOutList = M.fromList $ zip  [ 0 .. (tmOutListSize-1) ]  tmOutList
```

The code above deals with input (State, Symbol) pairs and output (State, Symbol, Direction) triplets. It provides lists of all possible pairs and triplets, `tmInpList` and`tmOutList`. A Turing transition table maps pairs to triplets.

The code also provides auxiliary indexing map objects, `tmMapInpList` and `tmMapOutList`, which map integer ranks to pairs and triplets within their respective lexicographically ordered lists. The reason to use **integer indexing** is that, even if it is possible to loop thru triplets directly, this turned out to be about 10 times slower than the *brute force* code provided below, which uses integer indexing systematically.

We have 2*3 = 6 possible input pairs, as the QF state is not allowed on input. We have 3*3*2 = 18 possible triplets on output. The number of possible transition tables is thus 18^6 = 34,012,224.

### Indexing and looping code:

In order to go thru all possible transition tables, we use integer lists of length 6, such as [4,6,8,2,13,10]. They go from [0,0,0,0,0,0] to [17,17,17,17,17,17]. Then these lists get mapped to lists of triplets.

These short integer lists are generated by the expression:

```
tmIndexList = sequence $ replicate 6  [ 0 .. 17 ]
```

The indexing code producing all 34,012,224 possible transition maps is given below:

```
tmIndexList :: [[Int]]
tmIndexList = sequence $ replicate  tmInpListSize  [ 0 .. (tmOutListSize-1) ]
tmIndexListSize = length tmIndexList


deltaTableFromIndexes :: [Int] -> DeltaTable
deltaTableFromIndexes indexList =
    let outFromIndex = (\ix -> Mb.fromJust $ M.lookup ix tmMapOutList)
    in  M.fromList $ zip  tmInpList  (map  outFromIndex  indexList)


-- big list of map objects mapping (st, sy) to (st', sy', dir)
deltaTableList :: [DeltaTable]
deltaTableList = map deltaTableFromIndexes tmIndexList

-- big list of  *functions*  mapping  st sy  to  (st', sy', dir)
deltaFuncList :: [DeltaFunc]
deltaFuncList = let funcFromMap ma = (\st sy -> Mb.fromJust $ M.lookup (st,sy) ma)
                in  map funcFromMap deltaTableList
```

The `deltaTableList` variable is a list of all possible map objects. The list version of a map object looks like this:

```
[((Q0,Zero),(QF,Blank,R)),((Q0,One),(QF,Blank,R)),((Q0,Blank),(QF,One,R)),((Q1,Zero),(QF,Blank,L)),((Q1,One),(Q0,Blank,L)),((Q1,Blank),(QF,Blank,L))]
```

The question text mentions functions not maps. However, it is more practical to use maps, as you can go from maps to functions, but not from functions to maps. Functions are opaque, so to speak. See definition of `deltaFuncList` above.

### Main program:

In order to force evaluation within the following main program, we print the map at rank 34,000,000 which is close to the end of the list.

```
prettyPrintMap :: DeltaTable -> String
prettyPrintMap ma =
    let ptrls = M.toList ma
        fn = \(p,tr) -> (show p) ++ " -> " ++ (show tr) ++ " ; "
    in  (concatMap fn ptrls)


main = do
    putStrLn $ "  tmInpListSize   = "  ++  (show tmInpListSize)
    putStrLn $ "  tmOutListSize   = "  ++  (show tmOutListSize)
    putStrLn $ "  tmIndexListSize = "  ++  (show tmIndexListSize)

    -- force printing of one transition table close to the end of the list
    let ma34m = deltaTableList !! (34*1000*1000)
    putStrLn $ "Plain  ma34m = " ++ (show ma34m)
    putStrLn $ "Pretty ma34m = " ++ (prettyPrintMap ma34m)
    putStrLn $ " "
```

### Execution with brief performance metrics:

```
$ ghc -O2 turing01.hs  -o turing01.x
$
$ time ./turing01.x +RTS -s -RTS

  tmInpListSize   = 6
  tmOutListSize   = 18
  tmIndexListSize = 34012224

Plain  ma34m = fromList [((Q0,Zero),(QF,Blank,R)),((Q0,One),(QF,Blank,R)),((Q0,Blank),(QF,One,R)),((Q1,Zero),(QF,Blank,L)),((Q1,One),(Q0,Blank,L)),((Q1,Blank),(QF,Blank,L))]
Pretty ma34m = (Q0,Zero) -> (QF,Blank,R) ; (Q0,One) -> (QF,Blank,R) ; (Q0,Blank) -> (QF,One,R) ; (Q1,Zero) -> (QF,Blank,L) ; (Q1,One) -> (Q0,Blank,L) ; (Q1,Blank) -> (QF,Blank,L) ; 

   5,873,144,856 bytes allocated in the heap
   3,516,995,416 bytes copied during GC
     886,616,408 bytes maximum residency (11 sample(s))
...

  %GC     time      76.6%  (76.6% elapsed)
  Productivity  23.4% of total user, 23.4% of total elapsed

real    0m3,692s
user    0m3,096s
sys     0m0,588s
```

So the *brute force* technique turns out to be feasible for the exact set of Turing states and alphabet provided in the question. Though of course, adding more states and symbols would quickly lead to a combinatorial explosion of the execution time.